# Showing that $2^6$ divides $3^{2264}-3^{104}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

> Show that $3^{2264}-3^{104}$ is divisible by $2^6$.

**My attempt:** Let $n=2263$. Since $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1 \pmod n$ and
$$\phi(n)=(31-1)(73-1)=2264 -104$$
we conclude that $3^{2264}-3^{104}$ is divisible by $2263$.

I have no idea how to show divisibility by $2^6$.

Comment: Your equation should be $a^{\phi(2^6)}\equiv1\pmod{2^6}$....After that you should proceed to show that each term is $\equiv0\pmod{2^6}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$3^{2264}-3^{104} = 3^{104}(3^{2160}-1)$

$\lambda(2^6) = 2^4 = 16$ where $\lambda$ is the [Carmichael  or reduced totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function)

$16 \mid 2160 \implies 3^{2160}\equiv 1 \bmod 2^6 \implies 2^6 \mid (3^{2160}-1)$

and $2^6$ divides $3^{2264}-3^{104}$ as required.

Comment: At first I had accepted Zev's reply as the answer. However, after studying Carmichael's theorem as referenced in this post, I've decided this is a better answer. This answer requires recognizing that 16 divides 2160, as opposed to recognizing that $3^{16}\equiv 1 \pmod {64}$.

Answer (score 9):

Note that
$$3^{2264}-3^{104}=3^{104}\cdot (3^{2160}-1)$$
and $\gcd(2,3)=1$, so $64$ divides this number if and only if it divides the factor $3^{2160}-1$. Since 
$$3^{2160}-1=(3^{16})^{135}-1$$
and $3^{16}\equiv 1\bmod 64$, we have that $(3^{16})^{135}\equiv 1^{135}\equiv 1\bmod 64$ and therefore $64\mid (3^{16})^{135}-1$.

Answer (score 7):

You've got $(3^{2160} - 1)\cdot3^{104}$.

The second half of that is obviously not divisible by $2$, so we must show that $3^{2160} \equiv 1\ (\text{mod}\ 2^6)$.

A quick brute force check of exponents of $3$ gives $3^{16} \equiv 1\ (\text{mod}\ 64)$; $2160=16 \times 135$.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: I would say it's pointless to worry about a downvote. Your solution looks good to me. It is a relatively elementary fact that the multiplicative group of residue classes moduloe $2^m$ of odd integers, $\Bbb{Z}_{2^m}^*$, has exponent $2^{m-2}$ so you can replace the brute force part of $3^{16}\equiv1$ by invoking that result. But I don't think that would explain a downvote.

Comment: Additionally to avoid brute force you can try using Euler's totient

Comment: $3^{32} = 1\mod64$

Comment: @sidt36: Normally Euler's totient gives the best general results modulo a prime power, but powers of two form an exception: $a^{16}\equiv1\pmod{64}$ for all odd integers $a$. We get this from the structure of that group. Observe that $2160$ is not divisible by $32$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think of this reduced order as  "inherited" by higher powers of $2$ from  $a^2 \equiv 1 \bmod 8$ for all odd $a$

Comment: That's a good way @Joffan ! So many IMO training problems depended on it that it became second nature :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That's not an exception.  Euler's totient works for a and n relatively prime, not just a prime.  For powers of 2 all odds are relatively prime so ... no exception.  Eulers totient claims $a^{\phi n} = 1 \mod n$ but it never claims $\phi n$ is the *smallest* such number.

Comment: @fleablood: I said that it gives the best **general** result for powers of a prime $p,p\neq2$. If $p>2$ then to each $m$ there exist integers $a,\gcd(a,p)=1$ such that $\phi(p^m)$ **is** the lowest exponent that works. If $p=2$, then we **always** get away with less. So $p=2$ **is** exceptional.

Comment: Ah, I see. Interesting.  Never thought of that.

Comment: No worries @fleablood I should have made it clearer the first time.

Answer (score 6):

Since $2264-104=2160=2^4\cdot 135$, we can write
$$3^{2264}-3^{104}=3^{104}(3^{1080}+1)(3^{540}+1)(3^{270}+1)(3^{135}+1)(3^{135}-1)$$
Here, note that 
$$3^{n}\pm1\equiv 0\pmod 2$$
and that
$$3^{135}+1\equiv (-1)^{135}+1\equiv 0\pmod 4$$

Comment: You don't actually need to know (or show) which of $3^{135}+1$ and $3^{135}-1$ is divisible by $4$ - they are adjacent even numbers so certainly one of them is.

Comment: @Joffan: Ah, you are right. Very nice! Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

*A variant with some details:*

By *Euler's theorem, $\;3^{\varphi(2^6)}\equiv 3^{32}\equiv=1\mod 2^6$. So
$$3^{2264}-3{104}\equiv3^{2264\bmod\varphi(2^6)}-3^{104\bmod\varphi(2^6)}\equiv 3^{24}-3^{8}\equiv3^8(3^{16}-1)\mod 2^6,$$
so it is enough to prove $3$ has order $16$ mod $2^6=64$.

Let's use the *fast exponentiation algorithm* mod $64$:
$$\begin{array}{r| l}
k & 3^k \\\hline
1&3\\2&9\\4&81\equiv 17\\8&289 \equiv-31\\16&961\equiv\color{red}{1}
\end{array}$$

*A nicer and faster computation* (after @Joffan's suggestion):

As $x\equiv a\mod 2^k\implies x^2\equiv a^2\mod 2^{k+1}$, we have
$$ 3 \equiv -1\mod 2^2\implies3^2 \equiv 1\mod2^3,$$
whence $3^{16}\equiv 1\mod 2^6$.

Comment: A pretty pattern on the square residues from $9=2^3+1, 17=2^4+1, 33=2^5+1$ (due to the square of the power of $2$ "modding out" )

Comment: @Joffan: Very nice! I've updated my answer (with credits).

Comment: I tried editing your post, but after a few days the edits are not posted. There are some typos: $3^{2264}-3^{104}\equiv3^{2264\bmod \phi(2^6)}-3^{104\bmod \phi(2^6)}\equiv \cdots$

Comment: @mhp: Fixed. Thank you for pointing it

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

$$\text{Euler's formula:  }\quad a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1 \pmod{n} \text{ when} \gcd(a,n)=1$$

$\implies a^{32}\equiv 1 \pmod{2^6}$

We want $3^{2264}-3^{104}\equiv 0 \pmod{2^6}$

$$\phi(2^6)=2^5=32$$

$$ 3^{2264}-3^{104}=3^{2240}3^{24}-3^{96}3^{8}=(3^{70})^{32}3^{24}-(3^3)^{32}3^8\equiv 3^{24}-3^8\equiv 17^6-17^2\\
\equiv 33^3-33\equiv \color{green}{0 \pmod{2^6}}$$

Answer (score 1):

If Euler/Carmichael are unfamiliar, we can instead use the Binomial Theorem

$\ {\rm mod}\ 8^2\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{3^{\large 16}}\equiv 9^{\large 8}\equiv (1\!+\!8)^{\large\color{#0a0} 8}\equiv 1 + \color{#0a0}8\cdot 8 + 8^2(\cdots)\equiv \color{#c00}{\bf 1}$

therefore $\ \ 3^{\large J+16K} - 3^{\large J} \equiv\, 3^{\large J}(\color{#c00}3^{\large\color{#c00}{16}K} - 1)\,\equiv\, 3^{\large J}(\color{#c00}{\bf 1}^{\large K}-1)\equiv 0\,\pmod{8^2}$

Comment: In other words, it is true if both exponents are congruent modulo $\color{#c00}{16}$, which is true in your case because we have that   $\  2264 - 104 \,=\, 2160 \,=\, 2000+160 \,=\, \color{#c00}{16}\,(125 + 10)\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

Just to give another way (*all the answers, including mine, are equivalent I guess*) and expose

**the division is exact** (i.e. $2^7$ does not divide $3^{2264}-3^{104}$).

$$3^{2264}-3^{104}=3^{104}(3^{2160}-1)=3^{104}(3^{1080}-1)(3^{1080}+1)=3^{104}(3^{8\cdot135}-1)(3^{8\cdot135}+1)=\\=3^{104}(6561^{135}-1)(6561^{135}+1)=\text{odd}(6560\cdot odd)(6562\cdot odd )$$ (*because the factors of $6561-1=6560$ and $6561+1=6562$ are both a sum of an odd number of odd terms*). It follows because of $6560=2^5\cdot5\cdot41$ and $6562=2\cdot17\cdot193$ that

$$3^{2264}-3^{104}
=\color{red}{\text{odd}\cdot2^6}$$